# Mix html form submit of Amazon s3 and server submission

Tags: html, flask, amazon-s3, multipartform-data, form-data

I am wondering how I can achieve this: For a user, he will see a form with submit button; in the background, I use JS to upload videos directly to S3, already successfully, so when "submit" is clicked, only variable1 and 2 are to be submitted; however, at this moment, the videos still get submitted through app redundantly, I can tell by execution speed. How to resolve this?

```
<form action = "{{ request.path }}" method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
id="mainform">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="variable1-ServerSubmit" id="..." >
<input type="file" class="..." id="video1-S3-submit" name="files[]"  >
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="variable2-ServerSubmit" id="..." >
<input type="file" class="..." id="video2-S3-submit" name="files[]"  >
<button class="submit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and found that, by removing names, the input won't be submitted. That seems to be the results i need.